# Network Card working only at 100

Tags: 16.04, networking, dell, nic

I installed Ubuntu 16.0 on a Dell 7010 desktop, but the network card only connects at 100mbps. I installed a second TPlink network card and that also works only at 100mbps.

The same network cards works at 1000mbps on windows 7 but not on Ubuntu.

My network cards are:

- Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
- Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)

Any advice please.

Comment: Most times when you see that it's connecting at less than the optimal speed, it's a cabling issue. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? Is the switch/hub/router/modem that it connects to gigabit? Otherwise, auto-negotiation can sometimes go wrong... but most times... it's cabling.

Comment: It is a gigabit switch and cat 5 cabling. i have tried different cabling. Same pc works  at 1000mbps with windows

Comment: Thanks heynnema, It did turn up to be a strange cabling issue. Tried in another part of the building and it works at 1000mbps. I was confused why it worked with windows and not ubuntu. Resolved the mystry

Comment: I put together a quick answer for you. Please remember to accept it if the advice was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

Most times when you see that it's connecting at less than the optimal speed, it's a cabling issue. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? Is the switch/hub/router/modem that it connects to gigabit? Otherwise, auto-negotiation can sometimes go wrong... but most times... it's cabling.

**Update #1:**

*It did turn up to be a strange cabling issue. Tried in another part of the building and it works at 1000mbps. I was confused why it worked with windows and not ubuntu. Resolved the mystry*